# Why does JS forin loop stores (looped) object as a (stringified) key, not an object?

Tags: javascript

This is something that's been bugging me.

I believe example speaks better, so let's say I'm using a Javascript object as a key-value storage:

```
var sessionsManager = {
  'initialized': true,
  'members': {
    'apple' : { 'time': '3498134911123' },
    'orange': { 'time': '3031239123193' },
    'foo'   : { 'time': '3230102301929' },
    'bar'   : { 'time': '3230102301929' }
  }
};

for(var session in sessionsManager.members) {
  console.log(session.time); // #1: 'undefined'
  console.log(sessionsManager.members[session].time); // #2: correct values
}
```

Notice the two lines of `console.log` at the end; `session` is not an object, but a string. why?

EDIT: Is there any way so that approach #1 produces correct values? If so, how?

Comment: This boils down to "because that's how the language was written".

Comment: BTW: Remember to check that sessionsManager.members.hasOwnProperty(session) before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because keys of an object are strings.

When you use `for..in`, you are basically saying "for each key `session` in the object `sessionsManager.members`, do..."

That's why `sessionsManager.members[session].time` works - you're putting the key back in the object to get the value.

Comment: Is there any way so that `session.time` produces correct values (instead of `sessionsManager.members[session].time`)?

Comment: Natively, no. This is the idiomatic way to iterate through an associative array. A lot of 3rd party libraries provide the functionality you're looking for however. Check out jQuery.each or _.each